# How to create a border across an entire row using grid-template-areas

Tags: css

I'm using grid-template-areas to create a grid effect for my site but I'm trying to get borders across the entire column and it's not working in two different ways:

Each cell only has a border so it gets cut off and isn't a single line.

It only goes the length of the text or content of the border.

Here are examples of what I mean:  https://codepen.io/aysong/pen/dyGwRaG

I tried the following but I don't think it did anything.

```
  grid-row-gap:2px;
```

[image]

In the image above, the italicized text has a bottom border but it only underlines the text. You can see it again with the Active Time and Yield top borders.

I'm basically just looking for an entire single top or bottom border that expands the row.

Comment: Alternatively look into grid-template-rows

Comment: Grid-row-gap is à good idea if you play with background colors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Divide and conquer!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<style>
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-container > div {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.part1{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    border-bottom: solid 1px red;
    border-top: solid 1px red;
}
.part2{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    border-bottom: solid 1px red;
}
.part3{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    border-bottom: solid 1px red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="grid-container">
        <div class="part1">
            <div class="item1">1</div>
            <div class="item2">2</div>
            <div class="item3">3</div>
        </div>  
        <div class="part2">
            <div class="item4">4</div>
            <div class="item5">5</div>
            <div class="item6">6</div>
        </div>
        <div class="part3">
            <div class="item7">7</div>
            <div class="item8">8</div>
            <div class="item9">9</div>
        </div>
      </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to chop you grid-containers up into rows themselves:

```
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item1">1</div>
  <div class="item2">2</div>
  <div class="item3">3</div>
</div>
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item1">4</div>
  <div class="item2">5</div>
  <div class="item3">6</div>
</div>
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item1">7</div>
  <div class="item2">8</div>
  <div class="item3">9</div>
</div>

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    'item1 item2 item3'
  grid-gap: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}

.grid-container > div {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, do not give `grid-gap` as it will create unnecessary separation between the cells. Have look at the code below, hope this is what you are looking for.

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    'item1 item2 item3'
    'item4 item5 item6'
    'item7 item8 item9';
  grid-gap: 0px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-container > div {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.item{
  border-top: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item1 item">1</div>
  <div class="item2 item">2</div>
  <div class="item3 item">3</div>  
  <div class="item4 item">4</div>
  <div class="item5 item">5</div>
  <div class="item6 item">6</div>
  <div class="item7 item">7</div>
  <div class="item8 item">8</div>
  <div class="item9 item">9</div>
</div>
```